# "No module named pygtk found" after gtk+2, gtk+3, and pygobject3 all installed to mac

Tags: python, macos, gtk, pygtk, pygobject

I am trying to get gtk to work on my mac.

Gtk+2, Gtk+3, and pygobject3 have all already been installed to my mac using homebrew:

[image: Terminal screenshot for the installs]

However, when I try to import gtk and/or pygtk into a python project, whether it be a 2.7.10 project or a 3.6.1 project, the following code is always highlighted, saying that the module doesn't exist (no module named pygtk found):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import pygtk
pygtk.require("3.22.16") '''For 3.6.1 version of python'''
import gtk
import gtk.glade
```

How do I get GTK to import into python projects on pycharm on my mac, and why isn't this working?

Edit: I get the following command output when trying to install Pygobject through pycharm:

> The directory '/Users/shihaoheng/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
>
> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyGObject (from versions: )
>
> No matching distribution found for PyGObject
>    (1)

When I try installing pygtk from PyCharm, I get this error:

> Collecting pygtk-shell   Using cached pygtk-shell-1.90.1.tar.gz
>       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>         File "/private/var/folders/hn/9m609ll170942x44r13zxg980000gn/T/pycharm-packaging/pygtk-shell/setup.py",
>   line 26, in 
>           from PyGTKShell.Core import pygtkshell_version
>         File "/private/var/folders/hn/9m609ll170942x44r13zxg980000gn/T/pycharm-packaging/pygtk-shell/PyGTKShell/Core.py",
>   line 26, in 
>           import gtk
>       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gtk'
>
> ```
> ----------------------------------------
> ```
>
> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   /private/var/folders/hn/9m609ll170942x44r13zxg980000gn/T/pycharm-packaging/pygtk-shell/

Answer (score 3):

I think pygtk is for Gtk2 only. You are installing Gtk3 (`pygobject3`)
Try this code:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
```

gi.repository contains the whole stack of Gtk objects like: Gtk, Gdk, GLib, GdkPixbuf... so you can import them all from there

Btw here is a few nice examples of code for Gtk3: http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html